# Tomcat configuration - multiple hosts

Tags: java, tomcat, war, restriction, hosts

I have three web services (WAR files_ from a third party supplier which are hosted in Tomcat.  Each web service will have a different URL (e.g. website1.com, website2.com, website3.com) and from the research and POC work that I have done, this can be achieved by using virtual hosts.

Two questions:
1. I would like to restrict access to two of the web services so that they can only be accessed by internal ip addresses.  How can this be done?
2. Each of the web services has a status check method which can be run to check if the service is working correctly (it polls the database and runs a few of the methods on the webservice).  When it checks methods on the web service, it uses localhost to call it.  However my Tomcat configuration is set to use host names and thus fails.  How can I get around this whilst still binding each web service to a host name?

Here is the host configuration from the Tomcat server.xml file:

```
  <Host name="website1.com"  appBase="adminapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  </Host>

  <Host name="website2.com"  appBase="packagingapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  </Host>

  <Host name="website3.com"  appBase="fulfillmentapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  </Host>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first part do one of the following:

- Set a firewall rule to restrict access to a white-list of IP
  addresses.
- A simple HTTP module will work. Just hard-code (or from config) the
  allowed IP/host and reject all others.

For the second part:

- Just change to:

  `<Host name="http://localhost:8080/yourWebName appBase="packagingapps"
  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

  </Host>`

Comment: Thanks.  If I made the change you mentioned for the second part, how would traffic be directed to the correct host when someone accesses website2.com?  Wouldn't the above restrict access to localhost only?  I want the ability to hit the url from website2.com and localhost

Comment: @Tariq I don't think you could have both: local and independent hosts at the same time. anyway when you restrict only for the internal IP addresses for your services access what's the point behind making it a domain host like website2.com??